# Office Time jquery script

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am looking jquery script (plugin) that allow quickly select Office Hours, like shown:

[image]

For selecting work hours, "mouse dragging" is used, so user can quickly select work hours via days of week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious option would be:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/

Good luck!